# Oil heater in a large room

Tags: heating, technique

I'm about to by an oil heater. One of the properties of a heater is the area of the room that the heater can heat. Say 15 m^2 or 20 m^2.
The question is: what will be if I use the heater in a larger room? Will it just do it's best without heating the room to desired temperature or will it break somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ultimate effect will depend on the exact heater.

In general it will always be working flat out as it can't put out enough heat to raise the room temperature to the desired level. This could shorten it's operational life.

You'll also have a cold room.